# AS3 XMLSocket works in WIN EXE but not on SWF

Tags: actionscript-3, sockets, flash

I'm trying to make a socket client in FlashAS3 for my socket server written in nodejs. I also have a mobile app client that communicates with it.

In AS3 I wrote some test code that works perfectly when I publish and run Windows EXE file but when publishing to SWF and opening in browsers it does not connect to server. Even all that "imports" do not help. The Code:

```
import flash.system.Security;
import flash.net.XMLSocket;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.IOErrorEvent;
import flash.events.SecurityErrorEvent;
import flash.events.DataEvent;

var xmlSocket:XMLSocket = new XMLSocket();
xmlSocket.connect("myserverhost", 88);

xmlSocket.addEventListener(DataEvent.DATA, onIncomingData);
send_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clickHandler);
disconnect_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, disconnectHandler);

function clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    xmlSocket.send(input_txt.text);
    input_txt.text = "";
}

function disconnectHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    xmlSocket.close();
    send_btn.enabled = false;
}

function onIncomingData(event:DataEvent):void
{
    var items:Object = JSON.decode(event.data);
    for (var index in items) {
        trace(index+" => "+items[index]);
    }

    if(items['hello']){
        output_txt.text += items['hello'] + "\n";
    }
    else if(items['description']){
        output_txt.text += items['description'] + "\n";
    } else {
        output_txt.text += event.data + "\n";
    }


    output_txt.verticalScrollPosition = output_txt.maxVerticalScrollPosition;
}
```

I have been googling and found advise to make a crossdomain.xml file but it does not work, this is it:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE cross-domain-policy SYSTEM "/xml/dtds/cross-domain-policy.dtd">
<cross-domain-policy>
  <allow-access-from domain="*" to-ports="*" secure="false"/>
</cross-domain-policy>
```

Comment: The problem was that I opened the swf\html in browser
in localhost domain like file://localhost/C:/Users/

When I transfered it to the server - it stopped failing but still it cannot get messages from the server

Answer (score 1):

Try calling `Security.allowDonain('*');` before `var xmlSocket:XMLSocket = new XMLSocket();`.

Comment: Thanks! The issue was that SWF was located on my pc , not on the server. But a new problem appeared - after connecting to server it disconnects immediatly...

Answer (score 0):

look for Security.loadPolicyFile

Special syntax allows policy files to be retrieved directly from an XMLSocket server.
For Example:
System.security.loadPolicyFile("xmlsocket://adobe.com:414");

Comment: Thanks! The issue was that SWF was located on my pc , not on the server. But a new problem appeared - after connecting to server it disconnects immediatly...